# How to crate new column based on time interval?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a new column, based on time interval of 6hours from datetime column how can I do that?

[image]

```
     C/A     UNIT   SCP       STATION LINENAME  DIVISION    DATE    TIME    DESC    ENTRIES EXITS

0   A002    R051    02-00-00    59 ST   NQR456W BMT 05/29/2021  00:00:00    REGULAR 7578734 2590325
1   A002    R051    02-00-00    59 ST   NQR456W BMT 05/29/2021  04:00:00    REGULAR 7578740 2590327
2   A002    R051    02-00-00    59 ST   NQR456W BMT 05/29/2021  08:00:00    REGULAR 7578749 2590340
3   A002    R051    02-00-00    59 ST   NQR456W BMT 05/29/2021  12:00:00    REGULAR 7578789 2590386
4   A002    R051    02-00-00    59 ST   NQR456W BMT 05/29/2021  16:00:00    REGULAR 7578897 259041
```

Comment: It's recommended to add your data as text, we can not copy the consents from the image, Please Take a look at [Why not upload images when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Also add your code and show what you have tried so far and what's the exact point where you had issue.

Answer (score 1):

pandas has `floor` function for time

```
df['DATETIME'].dt.floor('6H')
```

this column needs to be datetime type

```
    0   1
0   2021-06-06 00:00:00     2021-06-06 00:00:00
1   2021-06-06 01:00:00     2021-06-06 00:00:00
2   2021-06-06 02:00:00     2021-06-06 00:00:00
3   2021-06-06 03:00:00     2021-06-06 00:00:00
4   2021-06-06 04:00:00     2021-06-06 00:00:00
5   2021-06-06 05:00:00     2021-06-06 00:00:00
6   2021-06-06 06:00:00     2021-06-06 06:00:00
7   2021-06-06 07:00:00     2021-06-06 06:00:00
8   2021-06-06 08:00:00     2021-06-06 06:00:00
9   2021-06-06 09:00:00     2021-06-06 06:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a new column with date/time being 6 hours offset from `DATETIME` column, you can use [`pd.DateOffset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects), as follows:

```
df['New_DATETIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATETIME']) + pd.DateOffset(hours=6)
```